# read split input by space enter by user in textfield

Tags: java, c, input, split, space

I need to create a program that is able to detect syntax error in C language programming.
Let's say the grammar should be

```
printf("statement");
```

How could I create an interface that is able to detect if there's any error in the coding?
The output should be "Syntax error!Please try again" or "Well done!No syntax error"

My teacher advice me to use *stringtokenizer*. Can anyone help me with this?
I dont mind if the user need to space for each input such as:

```
**printf** (space) **("** (space) **statement** (space) **")** (space) **;**
```

Comment: why both `c` and `java`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the tokenizer function [in `c`] you are looking for is `strtok_r()`. Please check the details regarding the usage of this function in the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

However, this is going to be a *tricky* job. Best of luck with your efforts.